# CSS distinguish between hover on element and it's ::before pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-element

I tried using `attr()` to implement a custom tooltip, but the tooltip doesn't disappear when I move the mouse off the element onto the tooltip itself, is there a way to fix it without using a child element containing the tooltip text?

```css
[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}

[data-tooltip]:hover::after {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(100% + 8px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  max-height: 1.2em;
}

[data-tooltip]:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(100% - 8px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br>
<center>
    <span data-tooltip="tooltip text"> visible text </span>
</center>
```

Comment: so you want the tooltip to disappear when mouse is hovered on the tooltip itself?

Comment: Exactly, without creating another element inside the `<span>`

Comment: tooltip to be closed when you hover `tooltip text` also right?

Comment: Yes, so it will be visible if and only if the `visible text` part is hovered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use `pointer-events:none` on the tooltip, it will show the tooltip but it will be ignored by the cursor

```
[data-tooltip]:hover::before {
    content: "";
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: calc(100% - 8px);
    left: calc(50% - 8px);
    border-width: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```